# jQuery UI autocomplete in remote modal RoR

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, database, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement `jquery ui autocomplete` in my remote modal and it doesn't work whereas `autocomplete` works on regular static pages.

For the remote modal, I am using a combination of gems: [modal-responder-rails](https://github.com/Sento/modal-responder-rails) and [rails-bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/germanescobar/rails-bootstrap-modal)

Here is my `autocomplete` code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var data = $('#book_subcategory_name').data('autocomplete-source');
  var NoResultsLabel = "No Results";
  return $('[id*="book_subcategory_name"]').autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
  position: {
    my: "left+0 top+4"
  },
  source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);
            if (!results.length) {
              results = [NoResultsLabel];
            }
            response(results);
           },
  select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.label === NoResultsLabel) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          },
  focus: function (event, ui) {
           if (ui.item.label === NoResultsLabel) {
             event.preventDefault();
           }
         }
  }); // End of return
}); // End of jQuery



// Sets autocomplete drop down width equal to the root element width
jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._resizeMenu = function () {
  var ul = this.menu.element;
  ul.outerWidth(this.element.outerWidth());
}
```

Here is my modal, which I copied from this [article](https://jtway.co/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app-8c21213b4d0c).

Modal:

```
$(function() {
  var modal_holder_selector, modal_selector;
    modal_holder_selector = '#modal-holder';
    modal_selector = '.modal';
  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function() {
    var location;
    location = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(location, function(data) {
      return 
      $(modal_holder_selector).html(data).find(modal_selector).modal();
    });
    return false;
  });
  return $(document).on('ajax:success', 'form[data-modal]', 

  function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    var url;
    url = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
    if (url) {
      window.location = url;
    } else {
      $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
      $(modal_holder_selector).html(data).find(modal_selector).modal();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

The idea is to create a remote modal controller where you can add a new book. I have a multi-step registration which means that my modal has to redirect to a new page: `general information` if the information correct but I can't validate the forms since my `JavaScript` doesn't work...

I tried to overwrite `z-index` and also tried to use `!important` in my CSS and it still doesn't work. Also, if I look into my browser console, I can clearly see that all of the data appears in my `input` field (note: all of my data comes from the database) as shown below:

```
<input data-autocomplete-source="["Sci-fi","Adventure"...] />
```

I don't see any problem with the code and I can't figure out the problem. Can someone please help me to solve the problem?
Thank you very much for your help and time.

**UPDATE:**

As long as I understand, my problem comes from the rendered action page. Since I am rendering my modal body, `javascript` doesn't work.

One of the solutions I found is to add

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { ... }
end
```

somewhere in your `create` method (or action) which will identify the `create.js.erb` in your assets. However, if you want to render a `static` content (ex. map), I am not sure what to do here because, in order to define a modal, you have to add `respond_with_modal @books` inside your controller under the method that you want to use.

Comment: Do you really have improperly nested double quotes in your data attribute?

Comment: @muistooshort yeah, it works fine on any other form on every page, except modal (as far as I know)

Comment: Try fixing the data attribute first, it should look more like `<input data-autocomplete-source="['Sci-fi','Adventure'...]" />` no? At least then you'd be starting with valid HTML.

Comment: @muistooshort but why does it work on any other part of the website? I have autocomplete in my navigation bar search and it works...

Comment: @muistooshort will do so anyways, thank you

Comment: Does `$('[id*="book_subcategory_name"]')` find anything in your modal? My first guess would be a timing issue (possibly in the "The element I'm looking for doesn't exist because the modal isn't in the DOM yet" variant).

Comment: @muistooshort I will try to fix the data attribute first... maybe this is a real issue, thank you so much

Comment: `$(modal_holder_selector).html(data)` is suggestive, you'd have to bind everything inside `modal_holder_selector` after that call.

Comment: @muistooshort unfortunately, quotes not a problem

Comment: But what about the autocompleter binding *after* the modal is in the DOM?

Comment: @muistooshort I think the reason is because I am not loading `js` after modal appears, I tried to display `.on("click", function() {console.log("click");"});` and it doesn't work. Thank you very much for you help and time, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no working example, I just assume this its a timing issue like @muistooshort pointed out. You properly load your jquery part before the modal is updated. One option to overcome this, is by using Events. You want your code to be executed after your update your modal with the `html`-function.

Please try the following code:

```
$(document).on('modalUpdate', function(){
  var data = $('#book_subcategory_name').data('autocomplete-source');
  //... rest of your autocomplete code
});

//...start of your modal code
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
$(modal_holder_selector).html(data).find(modal_selector).modal();
$(document).trigger('modalUpdate'); //add this line
//...rest of your modal code
```

depending on your application, you might want to change the event to something like `contentUpdated`, so it fits a more general purpose. You can name the Event what ever you like. You can read more on the [jQuery article: Introducing Custom Events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately the problem was with `Ruby on Rails framework`, not with `jQuery`. The content that was inside the modal was rendered without any front-end code (except css of course). Anyways, thank you very much for your help and time!