# Reusable remote modal Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-modal, haml

I am trying to create a reusable remote modal. The idea is to create a model container and render content with `yield` into it and render content when needed.

Note: all `HTML` code will be written in `HAML`. I am using [bootstrap-modal-rails](https://github.com/vicentereig/bootstrap-modal-rails) gem to handle my modals.

My modal container layout (not a partial):

```
%div(class="modal" id="mainModal ajax-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"){:'aria-labelledby'=>"mainModalLabel", :'aria-hidden'=>"true"}
  %div(class="c-modal__container")
    %div(class="c-modal__layout modal__content") 
      = yield
```

In my `application.html.haml`, I have a div that defines the modal location as follows:

```
-# ...
%div(id="modal-holder")

- unless params[:nojs]
  = javascript_include_tag 'desktop'

-# ...
```

Here is where my problem comes from. I have a `book controller` where the user can add books. I have a multi-step registration and my `new` action have to be my modal. When the user clicks `New book` link, I am loading a new modal.

My `New book` link:

```
= link_to "New book", new_book_path, class: "c-link--navbar", data: { modal: true }
```

CoffeeScript(re-written in `jQuery`) for the modal (this code from [this article](https://jtway.co/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app-8c21213b4d0c)):

```
$(function() {
  var modal_holder_selector, modal_selector;
      modal_holder_selector = '#modal-holder';
      modal_selector = '.modal';
  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function() {
    var location;
    location = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(location, function(data) {
      return $(modal_holder_selector).html(data).find(modal_selector).modal();
    });
    return false;
  });
  return $(document).on('ajax:success', 'form[data-modal]', 

  function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    var url;
    url = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
    if (url) {
      window.location = url;
    } else {
      $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
      $(modal_holder_selector).html(data).find(modal_selector).modal();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

And now my `new action` for the `yield` that will be loaded inside my remote modal:

```
= form_for(@book, remote: remote, html: {role: :form}, class: "c-form") do |f|
  -# Forms here...
  = f.submit "Add a new book", class: "c-btn"
```

If the user's information correct, my modal will redirect the user to `general action` else I want to **stay on the same page** and flash an error message but the problem is that I am not using a `partial` and it automatically redirects me to a new page with `new action`.

My `books_controller.rb`:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :js
  ...

  def index
    @books = current_user.books
  end

  def new
    @book = current_user.books.build
    respond_modal_with @book
  end

  def create
    @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)

    if @book.save
      redirect_to general_book_path(@book), notice: "Saved."
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Something went wrong."
      render :new
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Modal Responder:

```
class ModalResponder < ActionController::Responder
  cattr_accessor :modal_layout
  self.modal_layout = 'modal'

  def render(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    if request.xhr?
      options.merge! layout: modal_layout
    end
      controller.render *args, options
  end

  def default_render(*args)
    render(*args)
  end

  def redirect_to(options)
    if request.xhr?
      head :ok, location: controller.url_for(options)
    else
      controller.redirect_to(options)
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to add something like

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @book }
end
```

to my `create` method but it doesn't work and still redirects me to the new page. Also, I've already asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957120/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-remote-modal-ror) and I've noticed that my `JavaScript` code works on a separate page. As long as I understand the problem is with my remote modal action page. Can someone please help me to figure out how to stay on the same page when the user entered the wrong input and turn on my javascript?

Comment: if you want your page not being redirected. Just return your ajax response without header: location

Comment: @plonknimbuzz I want to redirect on `ajax:success` and stay on the same page when `ajax:error`... I guess the problem with my ajax and controller settings. Thank you very much for the respond :)

Comment: Hello.. I checked your github profile. this is not an opensource project? It would be probably easy to find the solution by debugging this...if you let me fork your project otherwise I can get a deeper look

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Hi, I will create a new project in the next hour or two and will let you know here in the comments! Thank you very much for you help and time !

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I added you to the private repository. Thank you very much one more time :)

Comment: @AnthonyBrooks : sry yesterday i was busy. can you try this https://pastebin.com/werj49vP

Comment: @plonknimbuzz unfortunately this code won't work. The problem with my controller. When the modal opens, only `new.js.erb` works. I had the same problem with my `jQuery autocomplete` before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957120/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-remote-modal-ror)

Comment: may i look that with teamviewer? i still think this looks like client prob not server prob for me. i dont know ruby. but your code is still readable. and i really confuse why my fiddle didnt work.

Comment: @fabrizio : did you found any mistake with the controller?

Comment: I am still investigating your SO post. The reason you never get answer to you question is that you are not writing them correctly. You question has too many information and on a certain point of view it is very broad. My advice is trying to break down you problem in different pieces. For example, you have step 1, 2, 3, 4. Step 1,2,4 works because you debugged the process so step 3 is the problem. Then create a simple project were you recreate the issue (step 3) in a simplified way. The problem persist? then post it on SO. It does not? this is a clue you can use to solve the problem

Comment: for debugging I advice this gem https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

Comment: also usually you end up writing code like this (confuse and not DRY), when you do not write test specs (with Test Unit or RSpec). If you unit test you write good MVC code, you use inheritance, modules..etc.. so that you can test all those methods in the appropriate Unit/Class. If you are building a big project, I advice you based on my personal experience to write specs, do refactoring and write clean code so it is maintainable. You can read some books about this, it will help you

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I added you as a collaborator to my github project yesterday :)

Comment: sorry, your question would take more then my 30 minutes that I invest daily on SO, while many other questions are open in the ROR section that I can solve.. On average I get more then 50 points in 30 minutes on SO. So you understand, sometimes the best is posting a good question to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBH that's an abstract solution which is not directly related to your question, it works though (bootstrap+jq, based on production code)

**Coffe script**

```
$.showModal = (title, body) ->
    $("#modal").find(".modal-title").html(title)
    $("#modal").find(".modal-body").html(body)
    $("#modal").modal("show")
$("#modal").find(".modal-submit").click () ->
    $("#modal").find("form").submit()
```

**Html** - typical bootstrap modal

```
<div id="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="<%= t :close %>" title="<%= t :close %>">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><%= t :close %></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success modal-submit"><%= t :save %></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**new.js.erb** or another rails view

```
$.showModal(
    "<%= escape_javascript t :edit_comment %>",
    "<%= escape_javascript(render 'form', :comment => @comment) %>"
);
```

**link to open modal**

```
<%= link_to t(:new), [:new, comment], :remote => true, class: "btn" %>
```

You probably would like to use your own ajax request - this one would do nothing in case of server error/timeout

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Really appreciate your time. Will try to implement your solution.